# How can I export numbers between spaces in a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I want to input a `String` like this "5 4 34" from keyboard. How can I export the numbers between spaces? Also a want to export them into an `int[]` array, and print them on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much boilerplate:

```
List <Integer> numbers = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
for (String number : "5 4 34";.split ("\\s+")) {
    int v = Integer.parseInt (number);
    System.out.println (v);
    numbers.add (v);
}
```

Or using Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner ("5 4 34");
List <Integer> list = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int v = scanner.nextInt ();
    list.add (v);
    System.out.println (v);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`String.split("\\s")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the `String` to `String[]` and then use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) on each element to get the number as an `int`.

Alternatively, you can use a [`Scanner`](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html&ei=mc2eT6aGNsSRswadpKRK&usg=AFQjCNGIsPc-k02EuYm_B89nvn2-g7OMow&sig2=gjzHXp1LJbpXJfbQ2EEttg), and its [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method

Since the others have already showed you how it can be done with `split()`, here is an example how to do it with `Scanner`, directly from `System.in` (I am assuming that what you want, because you say you read it from keyboard, of course you can use any [`Readable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html) or a `String` to build your `Scanner`):

**Code:**

```
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputScanner.nextLine());
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
Integer[] arr = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

or if you want an `int[]` and not an `Integer[]` instead of the last line, use:

```
int[] arr = new int[list.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Integer x : list) { 
    arr[i++] = x;
}
```

To print the array just print the result of [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: amit and all people thanks. i have one more question. when i type the string i want when i press enter to display the array in screen. With your solution it happened when i press any char and press enter.

Comment: @user1366336: I editted the answer (first lines of the code), the thing is `Scanner` waits for the next int after the enter is pressed, to work-around it, you can use two scanners, one for input and one for the parsing, have a look at the editted code. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: i believe that understand that you say but i am student and i haven't the experience to perform. :/

Answer (score 2):

Add an exception handler and you're in good shape:

```
String values = "5 4 34";
String [] tokens = values.split("\\s+");
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String number : tokens) {
    numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(number);
}
```

Or like this:

```
String values = "5 4 34";
String [] tokens = values.split("\\s+");
int [] numbers = new int[tokens.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.valueOf(tokens[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] stringArray = "5 4 34".split( " " );
    int[] intArray = new int[ stringArray.length ];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < stringArray.length ; i++ )
    {
        intArray[ i ] = Integer.parseInt( stringArray[ i ] );
    }
```

Comment: ever heard of the simplified for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "5 4 34";
String[] components = string.split(" "); // [5, 4, 34]
```

Comment: Note it doesn't get you `int`s, a post processing will have to be done to get the `int`s.